# Dapper: Not able to parse Date from dbf(Error parsing column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper, dbf, dbo

I want to use dapper to query over dbf files. In my file example.dbf I have 7 columns:

- Version- string
- CreatedOn- Datetime
- Features- string
- CreatedBy- long
- ModifiedOn- Datetime
- ModifiedBy- long
- IsDeprecated- bool

```
    public class ExampleDBF : BaseAdminPortalClass
    {
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string Features { get; set; }
        public long? CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public long? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeprecated { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the query for this-

```
        public static string ExampleQuery(AppVersionsFilter objFilter)
        {
            StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
            sbQuery.AppendFormat(@"SELECT {1} Version,CreatedOn,Features,IsDeprecated,CreatedBy,ModifiedOn,ModifiedBy,IsDeprecated FROM {0} av",
                        GetTableName(Table.app_versions, Database.PineStemDB),
                        objFilter.Pagination ? "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" : "");
            string strCondition = "WHERE";
            if (objFilter.Version != null && objFilter.Version.Count > 0)
            {
                sbQuery.AppendFormat(" {0} Version IN @Version ",strCondition);
                strCondition = "AND";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objFilter.SearchTerm))
            {
                objFilter.SearchTerm.Trim('\'');
                objFilter.SearchTerm = "'%" + objFilter.SearchTerm + "%'";
                sbQuery.AppendFormat(" {0} (Version LIKE {1} ) ", strCondition, objFilter.SearchTerm);
                strCondition = "AND";
            }
            if(objFilter.IsDeprecated != null)
            {
                sbQuery.AppendFormat(" {0} IsDeprecated=@IsDeprecated ", strCondition);
                strCondition = "AND";
            }

            // Sorting
            objFilter.SortingColumn = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objFilter.SortingColumn) ? "Version" : objFilter.SortingColumn;
            sbQuery.AppendFormat(" ORDER BY {0} {1} ", objFilter.SortingColumn, objFilter.SortingOrder);

            // Pagination
            if (objFilter.Pagination)
            {
                sbQuery.AppendFormat(" LIMIT {0},{1} ", objFilter.PageNumber, objFilter.PageLimit);
            }
            return sbQuery.ToString();
        }
```

And Here is the Repository function for better understanding-

```
        public AdminPortalResponse AppVersions(AppVersionsFilter objFilter)
        {
            AdminPortalResponse objResponse = new AdminPortalResponse();
            try
            {
                objFilter.SetSqlPagingValues();
                string strQuery = Queries.Analytics.AppVersions(objFilter);
                IList<AppVersion> lstAppVersions = _objDBContext.Database.Query<AppVersion>(strQuery,objFilter).ToList();
                objResponse.FillResponse(lstAppVersions);
                if (objFilter.Pagination)
                {
                    objResponse.RecordCount = _objDBContext.Database.ExecuteScalar<int>(Queries.Common.RecordCount());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                objResponse.FillResponse(ex);
            }
            return objResponse;
        }
```

All the columns are ok except the Datetime type columns.
`Error parsing column 2 (CreatedOn= - Object)`.

- I also tried checking the table in DB if it has the same type of Data, and also checked query we are executing. All positive from this side.
- Not sure why I am getting this issue.
- May someone have a solution for this.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in the database?

Comment: Side note: your `SearchTerm` interpolation is dangerous, you should instead parameterize it the same way as the other values.

Answer (score 0):

As error message tell. The problem is DateTime field.

DB Side = DateTime with NOT NULL

App side = DateTime with NULLABLE

Other recommend is

1. Try to log you SQL query for see is generated correctly or not ?
2. Consider appendline instead insert space in SQL builder.